# Invoking the in-app billing service without setting a target package for the intent

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-security

I just received an email from Google Play stating:
"We detected that your app(s) listed at the end of this email are invoking the in-app billing service without setting a target package for the intent. This can enable a malicious package to bypass the Play store billing system and access items that have not been purchased."

This game is developed using Unity3D. I do not have any native knowledge of native Android. What should I do in Unity3D so that this is fixed? Thank you

Comment: can you show some of your code for the IAB ?

Comment: Can you explain if you are using UNITY'S OWN in-app-purchase system, or are you using some plugin?

Comment: I am using Soomla's in app

Comment: Ah OK.  You will really struggle, Kashi.  That is incredibly out of date.  These days, in app purchase is totally built-in to Unity.  It is free.  Nobody any more uses Prime31, Soomla etc.  The IAP built-in to Unity is trivial to use ... https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game

Comment: Yeah i integrated it along time ago. Okay i ll upgrade to this one. Thanks :)

Comment: @JoeBlow is spot on. Unity purchasing as very simple to integrate following the documentation.